# [CS50-SCRABBLE]tying to link a array of numbers representing each alphabet with a score array having score for each letter similar to scrabble

Tags: c, cs50

```
int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};
string word = get_string("Player 1: ");
int score[26];
int sum=0;
int i=0;
while (word[i]!='\0')//string to alphanum
{
    if (isupper(word[i]))
    {
        word[i]=(int)word[i];
        score[i]=word[i]-65;

    }
    else if (islower(word[i]))
    {
        word[i]=(int)word[i];
        score[i]=word[i]-97;

    }



    printf("%d\t",score[i]);

    i++;
}
printf("\n");
for (int j=0;score[j]!='\0';j++)
{
    score[j]=POINTS[score[j]];
    printf("%d \t",score[j]);
}
```

the code works for all the values apart from A\a, for some reason it stops working ,
ive first converted the input charater array(word[]) into interger array,then tried to link the score array ( represents alphabets position==> A-0,B-1,C-2,..,Z-25) to the POINTS array which represents the scrabble value for each letter (Z-10,A-1)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4iS1.png)

Comment: `for (int j=0;score[j]!='\0';j++)` doesn't make sense. `score` is not a string and 0 is the value you would store in it for `'a'` or `'A'`. You probably want to use the length of `word` to know when to stop.

Comment: i did try that method, but couldn't make it work for some reason , probably where i messed up ,

Comment: admittedly not Scrabble player here, but shouldn't score just be a running total of all the letters' values? Like, "my score for this word is 160". `score` as an array doesn't make sense to me, but maybe I just don't know how to play. Also, recommend checking [`isalpha`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isalpha) before you do anything, then converting the input [`toupper`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/toupper) or `tolower` just so you only have one math operation to do.

Comment: the way i thought of it was i could store the score for each letter in a array and then sum up the array in the end , i dont get what u mean by running total, ik there are efficient ways to solve this but this is my first time with strings and arrays so this is what came to my mind

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should not use such magic numbers: `score[i]=word[i]-65;` If you mean `'A'` then you should use `'A'`. Same for `'a'`. Using numbers makes your code hard to read and maintain. And theoretically you could come across some machine where `65` is not `'A'` because they might not use ASCII.

Comment: yeah, you could do it that way, but that seems needlessly complicated to me. Plus, what you have isn't going to work if you have a word with duplicate letters sense you're overwriting the position of the `score` array each time. You need to add to the score already there. By running total I mean something like `int score = 0` then loop thru the word and for each letter do `score = score + POINTS[word[i] - 'A']`, then at the end you'll have the total score for the word.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to keep a running total of each letter. Do you need to report the sub-score for each letter? If not, it's easier IMO to add them together in a single total.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that doing arithmetic on the symbol table values like `'A' + 1 == 'B'` etc is actually not well-defined or guaranteed to work, save for the symbols `'0'` to `'9'` where such a guarantee *is* made by the C standard.

This means that you *can't* have a look-up score table of 26 scores and calculate the index in that table based on character value subtracted by `'A'` (or 65). If CS-50 is saying otherwise, it is bad.

Luckily however, mainstream computers have lots of memory these days so we may create a look-up table like this instead:

```
const unsigned char letter_score [256] =
{
  ['A'] = 1, ['a'] = 1,
  ['B'] = 3, ['b'] = 3,
  ...
};
```

This is taking up 256 bytes instead of 26 but that's no big deal. We set up each index of the table through so called "designated intializers", the `['A'] =`  things - this is an easy way to create self-documenting code. Items left out of the array initialization are guaranteed to get set to zero, which is fine in this case.

As you noticed, this also eliminated the `isupper`/`toupper` etc run-time checks, if we just set `'A'` and `'a'` to the same value. That's an optimization for faster execution speed, at the cost of ROM memory.

Usage:

```
size_t length = strlen(word);
int score = 0;
for(size_t i=0; i<length; i++)
{
  score += letter_score[ word[i] ];
}
```

As you can see, there's no need for `score` to be an array, since we don't really need to know/preserve the information that letter number *n* gave x points. We just want to know the total score.

Comment: thanks for the post , cleared up a lot of things, well im not sure but the cs50 did intend to use the score array(POINTS[ ]) in some way, also im trying to solve it without the score array as mentioned in another comment and yours , i was trying soo long to make the score array work but couldn't because initialisation an array without size is much more complicated than the scope for this current question

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the replies , i got it to work ,things which u guyz suggested and i changed was removing score array and calculate the sum on the go ,that fixed up the code and got rid of all the confusion i had and it also compacted the code quite a bit

```
int compute_score(string word)
{
    int sum=0;
    int i=0;
    while (word[i]!='\0')//string to alphanum
    {
        if (isupper (word[i]))
        {
            word[i]=(int)word[i];
            sum+=POINTS[word[i]-65];
        }
        else if (islower (word[i]))
        {
            word[i]=(int)word[i];
            sum+=POINTS[word[i]-97];
        }
        i++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

This is the final code

and if someone wants the complete code , spoilers for someone trying to solve cs50 on thier own

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet
int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};

int compute_score(string word);

int main(void)
{
    // Get input words from both players
    string word1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
    string word2 = get_string("Player 2: ");

    // Score both words
    int score1 = compute_score(word1);
    int score2 = compute_score(word2);

    // TODO: Print the winner
    if (score1>score2)
    {
        printf("Player 1 Wins! by %d points\n",score1);
    }
    else if (score1<score2)
    {
        printf("Player 2 Wins! by %d points\n",score2);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Tie!\n");
    }
}

int compute_score(string word)
{
    int sum=0;
    int i=0;
    while (word[i]!='\0')//string to alphanum
    {
        if (isupper (word[i]))
        {
            word[i]=(int)word[i];
            sum+=POINTS[word[i]-65];
        }
        else if (islower (word[i]))
        {
            word[i]=(int)word[i];
            sum+=POINTS[word[i]-97];
        }
        i++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: `word[i]=(int)word[i];` isn't necessary.